# Spark Scala Serialization Error from RDD map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization

I have a RDD of format RDD[((Long, Long), (Long, Long))] and I need to covert or transform into RDD[((Long, Long), (Long, Long, Long, Long))] where second RDD tuple is based on a function from the first RDD.

I am trying to achieve this based map function but, I think am doing something wrong here. Please help me to solve the issue.

Here is the full code:

```
package com.ranker.correlation.listitem
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import scala.collection.Map

class ListItemCorrelation(sc: SparkContext) extends Serializable {

  def up_down(dirX: Long, dirY: Long): (Long, Long, Long, Long) = {
    if (dirX.equals(1)) {
      if (dirY.equals(1)) {
        return (1, 0, 0, 0)
      } else {
        return (0, 1, 0, 0)
      }
    } else {
      if (dirY.equals(1)) {
        return (0, 0, 1, 0)
      } else {
        return (0, 0, 0, 1)
      }
    }
  }

  def run(votes: String):  RDD[((Long, Long), (Long, Long, Long, Long))]   = {
    val userVotes = sc.textFile(votes)
    val userVotesPairs = userVotes.map { t =>
      val p = t.split(",")
      (p(0).toLong, (p(1).toLong, p(2).toLong))
    }
    val jn = userVotesPairs.join(userVotesPairs).values.filter(t => t._1._1.<(t._2._1))
    val first = jn.map(t => ((t._1._1, t._2._1), (t._1._2, t._2._2)))
    var second = first.map(t => ((t._1._1, t._2._1), up_down(t._1._2, t._2._2)))
    //More functionality
    return result
  }

}
object ListItemCorrelation extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val votes = args(0)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJoins").setMaster("local")
    val context = new SparkContext(conf)
    val job = new ListItemCorrelation(context)
    val results = job.run(votes)
    val output = args(1)
    results.saveAsTextFile(output)
    context.stop()
  }
}
```

When I try to run this script I am getting following error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not
>   serializable  at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:288)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:108)
>     at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2094)     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:370)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$map$1.apply(RDD.scala:369)  at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
>     at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:362)    at
>   org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.map(RDD.scala:369)   at
>   com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation.run(ListItemCorrelation.scala:34)
>     at
>   com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation$.main(ListItemCorrelation.scala:47)
>     at
>   com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation.main(ListItemCorrelation.scala)
>   Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException:
>   org.apache.spark.SparkContext Serialization stack:
>     - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.SparkContext, value: org.apache.spark.SparkContext@4248e66b)
>     - field (class: com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation, name: sc, type: class org.apache.spark.SparkContext)
>     - object (class com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation, com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation@270b6b5e)
>     - field (class: com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation$$anonfun$4, name:
>   $outer, type: class
>   com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation)
>     - object (class com.ranker.correlation.listitem.ListItemCorrelation$$anonfun$4,
>   )  at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationDebugger$.improveException(SerializationDebugger.scala:40)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializationStream.writeObject(JavaSerializer.scala:46)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.serialize(JavaSerializer.scala:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:295)
>     ... 12 more

This error happening while executing following line:

> var second = first.map(t => ((t._1._1, t._2._1), up_down(t._1._2,
>   t._2._2)))

I am very new to scala, please help me to find the right way to do this.

Comment: Push `SparkContext` down as an argument for `run`? With the current implementation it will be dragged all the way down, and since it is not serialization, cause a failure.

Comment: @geek: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

Put the `up_down` method on a companion object.  When any class variable is accessed within an RDD closure, the class (and everything in it, like SparkContext) is serialized.  Method parameters count as class variables here.  Using a static object will get around this:

```
package com.ranker.correlation.listitem
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.rdd._
import scala.collection.Map

object ListItemCorrelation {
  def up_down(dirX: Long, dirY: Long): (Long, Long, Long, Long) = {
    if (dirX.equals(1)) {
      if (dirY.equals(1)) {
        return (1, 0, 0, 0)
      } else {
        return (0, 1, 0, 0)
      }
    } else {
      if (dirY.equals(1)) {
        return (0, 0, 1, 0)
      } else {
        return (0, 0, 0, 1)
      }
    }
  }
}


class ListItemCorrelation(sc: SparkContext) extends Serializable {

  def run(votes: String):  RDD[((Long, Long), (Long, Long, Long, Long))]   = {
    val userVotes = sc.textFile(votes)
    val userVotesPairs = userVotes.map { t =>
      val p = t.split(",")
      (p(0).toLong, (p(1).toLong, p(2).toLong))
    }
    val jn = userVotesPairs.join(userVotesPairs).values.filter(t => t._1._1.<(t._2._1))
    val first = jn.map(t => ((t._1._1, t._2._1), (t._1._2, t._2._2)))
    var second = first.map(t => ((t._1._1, t._2._1), ListItemCorrelation.up_down(t._1._2, t._2._2)))
    //More functionality
    return result
  }

}
object ListItemCorrelation extends Serializable {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val votes = args(0)
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SparkJoins").setMaster("local")
    val context = new SparkContext(conf)
    val job = new ListItemCorrelation(context)
    val results = job.run(votes)
    val output = args(1)
    results.saveAsTextFile(output)
    context.stop()
  }
}
```